# aws lex human handoff / intervene

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-lex

So, I am building a solution for web and mobile platforms which provides users with some screens from where the data from the Database is retrieved and inserted by some forms. One of the core features of the application is a chat-bot with supervised learning.

> As per my understanding of the Lex API, it can share the current
>   websocket connection with other aws-services like **API Gateway and Lambda**.
>   Also, I have come to know that the human handoff is not provided out
>   of the box in Lex like DialogFlow API and Azure Bots.

Therefore, I am planning to share the same websocket opened by the Lex API for interacting with the user with the API Gateway ( as it supports websockets ) and thereby creating a human handover.

**Please suggest whether there is a better approach to this problem's solution or I am on the right path ?**

P.S. **My Application stack is Nodejs and Angular based and following is my app's architecture.**

[image: Architecture]